# Calculating days between two dates wrong output

Tags: java, date, calendar

There are a lot of replicate questions on this matter, I've looked through most of them and got to make my code, but it didn't work.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
String targetDate = "18/05/2015";

date2.setTime(formatter.parse(targetDate));
long diff = date2.getTimeInMillis() - date1.getTimeInMillis();
long daysPassed = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

System.out.println("Today is : "+formatter.format(date1.getTime()));
System.out.println("Target date is : "+targetDate);
System.out.println("Difference of days between them is : "+daysPassed);
```

With the output being :

```
//Today is : 17/05/2015 
//Target date is : 18/05/2015 
//Difference of days between them is : 0
```

It works but with a day less, I could just add +1, but it gives 0 if is the same day too so there's that...

I should say It's for a uni project and I can't use external libraries or something that hasn't been taught yet.

It also gives an annoying parse exception error that keeps going all over the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you output the timeInMillis of date1 and date2, you'll get 2 long values, for example:

```
1431964800000
1431916207715
```

and the diff is 48592285

This value can be explained as:

```
48592285 milliseconds
48592285/1000 = 48592.285 seconds
48592285/1000/60 = 809.87 minutes
48592285/1000/60/60 = 13.50 hours
48592285/1000/60/60/24 = 0.56 days
```

That's the reason why you got 0 between 2 dates you specified.

Comment: That makes all the senses! now, the solution being?

Comment: change formatter pattern to `dd/MM/yyyy hhmmss` and append ` 235959` to the targetDate string

Comment: In a realistic situation, I don't want to consider time and only the days, how to achieve that? I guess forcing date1 to be 00:00:00, but how?

Comment: for example: date1.setTime(formatter.parse(formatter.format(date1.getTime())));